# Django Queries Count and update

Tags: django, django-models, group-by, count, django-queryset

I  have the following two models ASPBoookings and Athlete. The Athlete model is linked to the ASPBookings model by the foreign key named athlete.

I was recently shown queries/subqueries with Views and I have been trying to use them (still learning) to provide a count of all bookings assigned to each athlete within the ASPBookings table. Once I then have the information I need the "number_of_asp_sessions" within the Athlete model to be automatically updated with each of the athletes bookings count.

e.g. Athlete ID 1, may have two bookings assigned. Athlete ID 2, may have one booking assigned. The number_of_asp_sessions should then show these numbers for each of the athletes.

Hope this makes sense and thanks for advance for any help. Appreciate it.

**Below is the code:**

**ASPBookings Model**

```py
class ASPBookings(models.Model):
    asp_booking_ref = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=1)
    program_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='asp')
    booking_date = models.DateField()
    booking_time = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=booking_times)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=durations, default='0.5')
    street = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=regions, default='Metro')
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    organisation_type = models.CharField(max_length=120,choices=organisation_types, default='Government School')
    audience_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    presentation_form = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=presentation_form_options, default='Face to Face')
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    comments = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=statuses, default='TBC')
    email_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    athlete = models.ForeignKey(Athlete, default= '1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contact_name
        
    # return URL after the POST has been submitted.
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('vistours:success')
```

**Athlete Model.**

```py
class Athlete(models.Model):
    athlete_ref = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=1)
    athlete_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    home = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=sports, default='1500m Runner')
    notes = models.TextField(default='None')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=genders, default='Not Specified')
    para_athlete = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    working_with_children = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    available_from = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    bfbw = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    latest_bfbw_session = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_bfbw_sessions = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10)
    asp = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    latest_asp_session = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_asp_sessions = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10)
    tours = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    latest_tours_session = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_tours_sessions = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.athlete_name

    # return URL after the POST has been submitted.
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

**VIEW**

```
def count_bookings(request):

    Athlete.objects.annotate(number_of_asp_sessions=Count('aspbookings')).update(number_asp_sessions=F('number_of_asp_sessions'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: What is `expiry_date` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a try at below:

```
Athlete.objects.annotate(number_of_asp_sessions=Count('aspbookings')).update(number_asp_sessions=F('number_of_asp_sessions')
```

This will count all asp bookings per athlete, then update the `number_asp_sessions` field based on the annotated field for all the athletes in one go.

EDIT:

I tried it and somehow I'm getting:

```
    FieldError: Aggregate functions are not allowed in this query
```

Seems I cannot use the annotated field for updating. For now this should work:

```
objs = []
for a in Athlete.objects.annotate(number_of_asp_sessions=Count('aspbookings')):
    a.number_asp_sessions = a.number_of_asp_sessions
    objs.append(a)
Athlete.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['number_asp_sessions'])
```

EDIT:

Ended up using subqueries ;) This should also work:

```
Athlete.objects.update(
     number_asp_sessions=Subquery(
          Athlete.objects.annotate(number_of_asp_sessions=Count('aspbookings')).filter(pk=OuterRef('pk')).values('number_of_asp_sessions')[:1]
     )
)
```

Comment: There is a typo :
`Count('aspbookings_set')`
because the name of the reverse relationship is not redefined

Comment: Thanks bdbd and Raphael, I tried your comment above 
def count_bookings(request):

        Athlete.objects.annotate(number_of_asp_sessions=Count('aspbookings_set')).update(number_asp_sessions=F('number_of_asp_sessions'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')) but I get the below error.  FieldError at /admin_bookings/athletes/all/
Cannot resolve keyword 'aspbookings_set' into field.

Comment: Full Error. Cannot resolve keyword 'aspbookings_set' into field. Choices are: asp, aspbookings, athlete_name, athlete_ref, available, available_from, bfbw, bfbwbookings, education, email, expiry_date, gender, home, id, latest_asp_session, latest_bfbw_session, latest_tours_session, notes, number_asp_sessions, number_bfbw_sessions, number_tours_sessions, para_athlete, phone_number, schooltourbookings, sport, tours, working_with_children

Comment: No, I got a different message "Joined field references are not permitted in this query"

Comment: When you helped me yesterday on the other query you used OuterRef for referencing the primary key, do we need to add something like that into the query. This was from yesterdays query  asp_bookings = ASPBookings.objects.filter(athlete=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-booking_date')

Comment: For just counting the bookings per athlete, we don't need subqueries. Ok let me check that error. Can you share here the exact line of code you have now

Comment: So I have kept it as you originally posted, but just added to a view. See code above in the post for the View.

Comment: Updated my answer. Not sure what's going on, but just so you can move forward in the meantime, I've added another approach that should work for now.

Comment: Amazing that worked thanks again for the help bdbd, really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234636/discussion-between-bdbd-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need annotate have a try once.

```
ASPBookings.objects.annotate(num_athletes=Count('program_type'))
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, whilst this does not bring up an error it does not allow me to update the field 'number_asp_sessions'. I tried adding the update to your code ASPBookings.objects.annotate(num_athletes=Count('program_type')).update(number_asp_sessions=F('num_athletes')) but then I get a similar message error above saying the Field Name 'number_asp_sessions' does not Exist.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the field `number_asp_sessions`.
What you are looking for is to access the reverse relationship to `ASPBookings` from `Athlete`

you can simply add a method to the model `Athlete`

```
class Athlete(models.Model):
    athlete_ref = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=1)
    ...
    ...
    def get_number_of_sessions(self):
        return self.aspbookings_set.all().count()
```

`aspbookings_set` refers to the ForeignKey referencing instances of the class `ASPBookings` viewed from an instance of the class `Athlete`